Why does 4-layer feed_forward_network regression predict a fixed number for all test samples?
I built a 4-layer feed forward network. However the prediction for the test sample are all the same.They are a fixed number. I have standardized the data into [-1,1]. I am not sure if there is something wrong with my code.
my data google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1nC48KTEftjYPjYBu5h43cHQt3jbSwhQA
python code are as follows:
# import and function
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l1

def R_oos_tf(y_true, y_pred):
    resid = tf.square(y_true-y_pred)
    denom = tf.square(y_true)
    return 1 - tf.divide(tf.reduce_mean(resid),tf.reduce_mean(denom))

# read data
X_trn = pd.read_pickle("X_trn.pkl")
X_vld = pd.read_pickle("X_vld.pkl")
X_tst = pd.read_pickle("X_tst.pkl")
y_trn = pd.read_pickle("y_trn.pkl")
y_vld = pd.read_pickle("y_vld.pkl")
y_tst = pd.read_pickle("y_tst.pkl")

# features
features = list(set(X_trn.columns).difference({'permno','DATE','ret_exc_lead1m','ret','ret_exc'}))

# feed forward network- 4layer
mod = Sequential()
mod.add(Input(shape=(X_trn[features].shape[1],))) 
mod.add(Dense(32,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01)))                
mod.add(Dense(16,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01)))       
mod.add(Dense(8 ,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01))) 
mod.add(Dense(4 ,activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l1(0.01))) 
mod.add(Dense(1))
mod.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=[R_oos_tf])
mod.fit(X_trn[features], np.array(y_trn).reshape((len(y_trn),1)), epochs=10, batch_size=200, validation_data=(X_vld[features], np.array(y_vld).reshape((len(y_vld),1))))
nn4_pre = pd.DataFrame(mod.predict(X_tst[features]),columns=["nn4"])

# all the prediction is a fixed number!!??
nn4_pre.nn4.value_counts()
# result 0.007084    2911


I want to know what happened and why my prediction for over 2000 rows are a fixed number.

First the fact that "DATE" is one of your features stands out - that doesn't seem like a good idea. If this is time series data, you probably want to decompose date into repeating features like year, month, day of week etc. Second, your training data may be imbalanced, so the model learns to always predict the majority class. You should probably do some exploratory analysis on your features first.

Many thanks for your reply.  1) Yes, the 'DATE' is in the training sample. But in the training process, I filter the DATE by using 'features', as you can see the X_trn[features], X_vld[features] in my code.  2) Could you please explain more about the imbalanced part? I have done some exploratory analysis. What kind of variables I should not take into consideration when do modelling?

Looking at your model it looks like a binary classifier (i.e. the last layer outputs a single value). So I would start by counting how many "positive" and "negative"  (or whatever your target labels are) you have in your dataset. If say you have 90% positives, then you model could get 90% accuracy simply by predicting positive every time.

Also I'd probably start with 1 feature, one that has a high degree of correlation with your target, and maybe 1 layer  and use that to try and get the model converging. And check that all values in the features and target arrays are numeric etc.

Thanks for teaching me your method. My task is regression not classification though and the target is almost normally distributed. I have done 1-3 layers, the predictions of which are  not good but is not a fixed number. I will try to start with 1 feature. Thanks！If there‘s other suggestion, I would like to accept and try. Thank you!

You may also want to try disabling evaluation (i.e. don't pass the test dataset to fit, and don't pass metrics to model.compile) until you get training working. Whilst overfitting your training data isn't a good thing, it can be helpful as an initial check. If this works then maybe your evaluation function has an issue.
